# How to fetch arrays from a specific document in firestore and populate my local lists with that data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

Hello what I'm trying to do is just to populate a couple of lists that fill a **DropdownButtonFormField()** and the others according to what value is selected from the dropdownlist a specific list will be sent to the **SearchDelegate()** class where one can browse through the list, all of this I managed to make it work with local data but now I want to change that and save that local data in **firestore** and I did, but the problem that I encountered is that I can't seem to figure out how to fetch those arrays and populate my lists accordingly, this is what I managed to do so far.

Help is very much appriciated :)

[image: My Firestore collection and document]

My service class:

```
class LocationsService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<void> getLocations(){
    return _db
        .collection('locations')
        .doc('location')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      statesList = List<String>.from(value.data['states']);
      albanianCities = List<String>.from(value.data['albanianCities']);
      ...
    });
}
```

My local lists:

```
List<String>? stateLists = [];
List<String>? albanianCities = [];
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
statesList = List<String>.from(value.get('states') as List<dynamic> );
albanianCities = List<String>.from(value.get('albanianCities') as List<dynamic>);
```

Because you are trying to read one specific field in your document, you can use the `get("keyName")` method. For example you want the list which sits at the key `states`, you use `get('states')`.

If you wanted all the field, you use `value.data()`. Pay attention to using `()` in `data()`, which returns them as a `Map<String, dyanmic>`.

Comment: I did try to do that earlier and just tried it again but it still gives me the same error :(

Comment: That doesn't make sense. how about this: `statesList = List<String>.from(value.get('states') as List<dynamic>);` ?

Comment: Yes as soon as I commented i Tried to make the right hand value as a List and it worked ```statesList = List<String>.from(value.get('states') as List);``` Thank you :)